# Re-initialize template with new id on selectbox change

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a selectbox in template A which selects an item "name and id".

I also have an "item" template that needs an ID as parameter to load its data from its database. I am using a session variable for the id and I pass the id to the "item" template using return Session.get . This only works for on load. When the session variable change the "item" template is not updated. How do I get the "item" template to re-initialize

Some code:

```
 Template.selectBox.helpers({
    selectList: function () {
        return Templates.find({}, {fields: {'_id': 1, 'name': 1}});
    },
    selectedId: function() {
        return Session.get("selectedId");
    }
});

Template.selectBox.events({
    'change #item-chooser': function (event) {
        var selectedId = $(event.currentTarget).find(":selected").val();
        if (typeof(selectedId) === 'undefined'
            || selectedId === "new") {
            Session.set("selectedId", "new");
        }
        else {
            Session.set("selectedId", selectedId);
        }
    }
});
```

The items template is called using

```
        {{> item selectedId}}

Template.item.onCreated(function() {
    var selectedId = this.data.selectedId;
    this.selectedItem = new ReactiveVar;
    if (typeof(selectedId) === 'undefined'
        || selectedId === "new") {
        this.selectedItem.set(emptyItem);
    }
    else {
        var selectedItemData = Templates.findOne({_id: selectedId});
        this.selectedItem.set(selectedItemData );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that the [Template.onCreated](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onCreated) method is not reactive so if you have reactive variables, this method does not automatically re-run when a reactive data source changes unlike [Template.helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers)

The easiest way to fix your problem would be to use [autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun)

```
Template.item.onCreated(function(){
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        // some code that has a reactive data source (e.g. Session Var, Collection, or Reactive Var
        // NOTE: you can access template instance data using self.data
    });
});
```

However, based on your description, I think there could be a better way to handle your problem using [Template.helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers)

```
Template.item.helpers({
    selectedItem: function(){ 
        return Templates.findOne({_id: Session.get("selectedId")});
    }
});
```

Comment: You are of cause right. I have been trying session, reactivevar just to try out the differences but your helper method seems the most appropriate. Thanks